# Manipulate the <html> or <body> tag in React

Tags: dom, reactjs

What is the best way to manipulate the `<html>` or `<body>` tags in React?

For example, dynamically setting 'lang' attribute or change classes?

```
<html lang="en" class="ltr">
```

I could do that using raw DOM manipulation. But is this the right way?

Comment: Yes, raw dom manipulation is the right way. Follow the example of https://github.com/gaearon/react-document-title

Comment: Specifically take a look at [react-side-effect](https://github.com/gaearon/react-side-effect), which is what react-document-title is built with

Answer (score 34, accepted):

I've just encountered this use case where I want to modify the `<html>` lang attribute when language is switched by the user.
[React Helmet](https://github.com/nfl/react-helmet) made this quite simple actually.

First, install [React Helmet](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-helmet) with `npm install react-helmet`. Then import the **Helmet** component to your own component:

```
import {Helmet} from "react-helmet";
```

and then, just get the lang from your react state and pass it to the Helmet component anywhere in your app:

```
<Helmet htmlAttributes={{ lang : this.state.lang }}/> // with this.state = { lang : 'en' }
```

Answer (score 37):

It's ok to change the lang property directly and you may do so changing the value of 
 `document.documentElement.lang`

For example:

```
var newLang = 'fr';
...
document.documentElement.lang = newLang; // will set the lang property to 'fr'
```

Comment: I like this one because it doesn't require adding a library to the app

Comment: this should be the answer

Comment: if changing dir/lang attributes is all you need to do, it's not worth installing react-helmet

Comment: how can I use it when the key is for example data-theme?

Comment: @otto If you need to change data attributes you can alter the corresponding property in the dataset of the desired element (see "javascript access" section in [this MDN article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes#javascript_access), it's quite simple)

Comment: Since changing the language of the document is a side-effect, I'd say this belongs inside of a `useEffect` callback.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative syntax to the one in [Freezystem's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41920330/2072165), taken from the [helmet reference guide](https://github.com/nfl/react-helmet#reference-guide):

```
<Helmet>
  <html lang="en" />
</Helmet>
```

This could be rendered from within anywhere in your component tree. Naturally, you could use a dynamic value instead of `"en"`.

Answer (score 0):

## Update

Many of the answers provided here were good and do solve the problem. But instead of using [react-helmet](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-helmet) use [react-helmet-async](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-helmet-async) (*as react-helmet stopped being maintained in 2020*)

So these would be the steps to set it up:

```
// App.tsx

function App() {
  return (
    <HelmetProvider>
       <Helmet>
         <html lang="en" />
       </Helmet>
    </HelmetProvider>
  )
}
```

---

**Note:** You can use `<Helmet>` anywhere in your code. But you must place the `<HelmetProvider>` component at the top of your components' tree.