# React toggle body class when state is changed

Tags: reactjs

I have a menu button on my site that when I click it I am toggling the visibility of the site menu. How can I also toggle a class on the site Body element when the menu button is visible, so that I can prevent vertical scrolling?

```
// App.js

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Header />
    </div>
  );
}
```

--

```
// Header.js

function Header() {
  // Set menu button default state
  const [active, setActive] = useState(false);

  return (
    <>
      // Menu Button
      <button
        onClick={() => setActive(!active)}
        type="button">
          <span className="is-block">{active ? 'Close' : 'Menu'}</span>
       </button>

       // Menu Links
       <div className={active ? 'c-navigation is-active' : 'c-navigation'}>
         <li>Link 1</li>
         <li>Link 2</li>
         <li>Link 3</li>
         <li>Link 4</li>
       </div>
    </>
  )
}
```

Comment: Probably a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34237420/manipulate-the-html-or-body-tag-in-react

Comment: @IanMercer Thanks, but this isn't the same thing. I am asking how to toggle a class on the Body element when a button is clicked.

Comment: The question there is how to manipulate the head or body tag including changing class on it. Take a look the answers and React-helmet: it can do body tag too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

doing something like this:

```
document.body.style.overflow = "hidden";
```

and don't worry you're not manipulating the DOM that React is rendering, you're manipulating its parent.

```
    function Header() {
  // Set menu button default state
  const [active, setActive] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (active) {
      document.body.style.overflow = "hidden";
    } else {
      document.body.style.overflow = "unset";
    }
  }, [active]);

  return (
    <>
      // Menu Button
      <button onClick={() => setActive(!active)} type="button">
        <span className="is-block">{active ? "Close" : "Menu"}</span>
      </button>
      // Menu Links
      <div className={active ? "c-navigation is-active" : "c-navigation"}>
        <li>Link 1</li>
        <li>Link 2</li>
        <li>Link 3</li>
        <li>Link 4</li>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this, how do I use it within my example though?

Comment: you can use that in useEffect , check again i updated my response

Comment: Thank you! this works how I needed it to. I just adjusted the code so that it added/removed a class name on the body tag instead of adding CSS style to it

Comment: that's good :)))))