# How to show characters from Latin-1 Supplement in React?

Tags: html, reactjs, unicode, utf-8, character-encoding

My React-static website shows � instead of ø, on my page /src/pages/info.js

```
import React from 'react'

export default() => (
<div>
<p>
Here I want to type ø
</p>
</div>
)
```

From this answer [Manipulate the <html> or <body> tag in React](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34237420/manipulate-the-html-or-body-tag-in-react)

I tried to set the html lang tag by adding the following to App.js :

```
var newLang = 'da';
document.documentElement.lang = newLang;
```

But my source still builds to `<!DOCTYPE html><html lang="en-US" data-reactroot=""><head><meta charSet="UTF-8"/>`

I also tried to use the uft-8 code:
U+00F8
in brackets, in quotes, but the built site just shows the code instead.

The font I am using is Arial. From my css:
`font-family:  Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;`

Comment: Where does the `ø` originate? In source file? Just convert it in UTF-8. On resource file? Check if you can convert it as UTF-8. From database? Check the interface of database (encoding), ... HTML uses the entity/escape `&#x00F8;`

Comment: Thanks, it worked