# CSS hyphens not appearing in a wrapped word in Firefox 52

Tags: css, firefox, hyphenation

I've looked through several questions and forums and have been unable to find an answer. I saw [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28976543/css-hyphens-not-working-in-firefox), but it's solution didn't work for me.

I can confirm this problem is happening for me on both windows and mac Firefox.

```css
div {
  width: 200px;
  padding: 0 15px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
p {
  font-size: 16px;
  -ms-word-break: break-all;
  word-break: break-all;
  -webkit-hyphens: auto;
  -moz-hyphens: auto;
  hyphens: auto;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p lang="en">Better Life Expands Commitment to the Environment
</div>
```

For me, in Chrome is breaks the word "Commitment" to two lines "Commit-ment" with a hyphen. Firefox it cuts the word into "Commitme" and "nt", but fails to enter a hyphen.

I've tried all lowercase, various sizes, inserting `&shy;` and using manual, but nothing seems to work. Have I missed something that would lead to a solution?

Comment: I'm afraid you won't be successful, you can find many non-working answers on SO :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just erase the `word-break: break-all;` - works here in Firefox:

```css
div {
  width: 200px;
  padding: 0 15px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

p {
  font-size: 16px;
  -webkit-hyphens: auto;
  -moz-hyphens: auto;
  hyphens: auto;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p lang="en">Better Life Expands Commitment to the Environment
</div>
```

Here's a screenshot of the result (Firefox Mac):

[image]

Comment: @moped This is actually the solution I was looking for, I apologize for any confusion. Basically, I want a word to wrap to the next line with a hyphen, which this solution solves. Out of all the combinations I've tried, I never thought to remove word-break...Thank you!!!

Comment: OK, I assumed she wants those words with hyphens, sorry .. anyways, strangely it doesn't work in Edge, Vivaldi 1.8, Chrome :/

Comment: Interesting. For me it is working in Chrome(57) and FireFix(52), but on IE11 it wraps the word instead of breaking it, which honestly is fine for my purpose. I am unable to test in edge at the moment, working on Mac with a windows 7 VM.